# Slideshow Javascript Code - Page works fine without JS, not working with JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a slideshow with HTML, CSS and JS. Everything works unless I've added the JS code to it.
Here's the HTML code :

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/1.jpeg')">
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
        <button>Order Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpeg')">
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
        <button>Order Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/3.jpeg')">
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
        <button>Order Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/4.jpeg')">
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
        <button>Order Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-control">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS Code:

```
var slideIndex = 0;

showSlide();

var timer = setInterval(showSlide, 20000);

function showSlide(){
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementByClassName('slide-item');
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if(slideIndex > slides.length){
        slideIndex = 1;
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block';
        dots[slideIndex-1].className = 'active';
    }
}
```

Additionally, In CSS, I've set:

```
.slide-item{
   display:none;
}
```

Where am I doing it wrong ? Javascript seems to be causing these errors. Before adding JS, I see 4 images with captions but after adding JS, everything is gone. I've included the latest jquery script too.

Comment: "causing these errors" which errors?

Comment: I don't see any element with `id` of `slide-item` it is a class...

Comment: When I remove the JS script I can see 4 images with captions. But after adding JS, its just white screen

Comment: `var slides = document.getElementById('slide-item');` should be `var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-item');` (or `var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-item');`)

Comment: Changed .getElementByID to .getElementByClassName
Still not works.

Comment: Anyway you have to review your loops and how you use `slideIndex` (you will see the errors in console)

Comment: You have hidden all slides by default now, and you only make slides show again wrapped inside `if(slideIndex > slides.length)` - which won’t be the case, until your have iterated through _all_ your slides (with 20 seconds “delay” between each time) once …

Comment: Had to replace .getElementByClassName to .getElementsByClassName

Comment: With the css present, but no js, what do you see? My guess is that the css is causing the 'white screen' problem (ie everything important is display:none). The problem with the js is that your arrays are empty. First you used `document.getElementById('slide-item')` which doesn't return an array. Then you used `document.getElementByClassName`, which is missing the plural 'Elements'. I strongly recommend opening the console and using console.log

Comment: Console Errors shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showSlide (script.js:20)
    at script.js:3

Comment: Yes CSS is making the white screen because I want JS to display one image at a time, By changing the style display:none to display:block

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is that your code that actually shows the slides is inside this if condition so nothing will be shown until that is met:

```
  if(slideIndex > slides.length){
    slideIndex = 1;
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block';
    dots[slideIndex-1].className = 'active';
}
```

Another problem is how you are modifying the classes. Please use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API for safely manipulating classes.

Working example:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;

function showSlide() {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide-item');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove('hidden');
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');
}

showSlide();
var timer = setInterval(showSlide, 2000);
```

```css
.slideshow {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.slide-item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/1.jpeg')">
    <div class="caption">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
      <button>Order Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpeg')">
    <div class="caption">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
      <button>Order Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/3.jpeg')">
    <div class="caption">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
      <button>Order Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item bgimg" style="background-image: url('images/4.jpeg')">
    <div class="caption">
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>Some text here because you're not ready to give me content!</p>
      <button>Order Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-control">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at 
slides[slideIndex-1].classList.remove('hidden');

Comment: @user8579596 run the above snippet it doesn't have such an error.